# Pandas slice_replace with series

Tags: python, pandas

The current `slice_replace` method does not accept a `pd.Series` as `repl` argument:

MWE:

```
# Example as in the doc
pd.Series(['azerty_0', 'azerty_1']).str.slice_replace(1, 3, repl='repl')
Out[28]: 
0    areplrty_0
1    areplrty_1
dtype: object

# Passing a pd.Series does all combinations
pd.Series(['azerty_0', 'azerty_1']).str.slice_replace(1, 3, repl=pd.Series(['repl_0', 'repl_1']))
Out[29]: 
0    0    arepl_0rty_0
1    arepl_1rty_0
dtype: object
1    0    arepl_0rty_1
1    arepl_1rty_1
dtype: object
dtype: object

# Expected result
pd.Series(['azerty_0', 'azerty_1']).str.slice(0, 1) + pd.Series(['repl_0', 'repl_1']) + pd.Series(['azerty_0', 'azerty_1']).str.slice(3)
Out[30]: 
0    arepl_0rty_0
1    arepl_1rty_1
dtype: object
```

Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find any better alternative, one this you can use instead of slice function is list slicing over str i.e

```
s = pd.Series(['azerty_0', 'azerty_1']) 
rep = pd.Series(['repl_0', 'repl_1'])

new = s.str[:1]+ rep +s.str[3:]
```

Another one liner is:

```
new = s.str.partition('ze').rename(columns={1:'x'}).assign(x=rep).sum(1)
```